# Is it correct to use unset($form['#token']);

Tags: forms

In my Drupal 7 site, form submit throws the following error:

> The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then reload this page.

Is it correct to use `unset($form['#token'])` to resolve that error?

Comment: It's not a correct way, as you've to figure out what causing that your form being outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A big **NO** would be the answer but I think you guessed that already.

Form tokens are an important piece of security, insuring your form has not been forged by some script/bot and helps preventing malicious attacks. You can find some more information on drupal.org about it but consider it as a *must-have* or *should-not-remove* feature of you prefer.

If you have an issue with a form submit, you have probably hacked the form too much and should identify which part of your code has generated this error (some module might be in fault as well). Post an issue about this specific part but unsetting `$form['#token']` is not a viable solution.